# How to permutate an SQL table using a seed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

#### Background

I have a front-end with a list of items with infinite scrolling, and I fetch pages of items by specifying the page limit and offset.

#### Problem

Apart from simply ordering the result by some of the columns, I would like to add a "random" option. The thing is, I don't want repetitions, so I need to have the entire dataset permutated before doing the limit and offset, and I need to be able to get the same permutation as long as I supply the same seed.

#### What I tried

A naive approach was to write a table-valued function that takes an `int` seed and uses it in the `ORDER BY` clause like so:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Entities e
ORDER BY HASHBYTES('MD2', e.Title) ^ @seed
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Entities) ROWS ONLY
```

This seemed to work well at a first glance, but it turned out it's not very "volatile" for the lack of better word - it becomes more visible with sparse result sets, where most seeds (chosen randomly from between 0 and 2147483647) yield the same order.

I thought I would get better results by hashing the seed as well, but SQL Server doesn't allow me to XOR two `varbinary` variables. Am I even looking in the right direction? Are there any performance considerations that I should be making and I might not be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a tally table with two columns: first a sequential integer, (between 1 and 1,000,000), second a random integer number. Then generate a random number to get the first value and then make a join with a computed ROW_NUMBER().

```
CREATE TABLE T_NUM (SEQUENTIAL INT, RANDOM INT);
GO
WITH 
N AS(SELECT 0 AS I
     UNION  ALL  
     SELECT I + 1 
     FROM   N
     WHERE  I < 9)
INSERT INTO T_NUM (SEQUENTIAL)
SELECT N1.I + N2.I * 10 + N3.I * 100 + N4.I * 1000 + N5.I * 10000 + N6.I * 100000 
FROM   N AS N1
       CROSS JOIN N AS N2
       CROSS JOIN N AS N3
       CROSS JOIN N AS N4
       CROSS JOIN N AS N5
       CROSS JOIN N AS N6;
GO
WITH T AS
(
SELECT SEQUENTIAL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())) AS ALEA
FROM   T_NUM
)
UPDATE N
SET    RANDOM = ALEA
FROM   T_NUM AS N
       JOIN T ON T.SEQUENTIAL = N.SEQUENTIAL;
GO

DECLARE @SEED INT = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 1000000);
```

Now you have your seed to enter in the alea sequence then join your table on sequential order

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY HASHBYTES('MD2', e.Title + convert(nvarchar(max), @seed))
```

should work, but performance-wise it would be a disaster. You would calculate MD2 for all records every time. I would not do this on server side at all. You can generate random sequence on client and then just pick from server rows with row number 158, 7, 1027 and 9. But it has still two problems

- if item is deleted, row number of all consecutive records shifts. It would just break the whole sequence and you would get duplicities and missing records
- row number over millions of records is not that fast either

I see two options. You can query all ids from the table and use them for generating of random order. But that would be a lot of numbers. Or you have to ensure the id space is dense enough. Then you can query 20 random ids and hope at least 10 of them exist. If you are unlucky, you would have to query again.